# How to display correctly this string on an alert javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery

I have this string :

```
myString="Citt&agrave;"
```

and I'd like to display correctly (as Città) on an alert in Javascript. How can I do it from C# using Javascript/jQuery?

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/vQ8Ga/) for the example

Comment: if I do alert(myString) I see Citt&agrave;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you don't need to use that notation in javascript. If you run `alert('Città')` the browser will show it correctly.

Comment: You think? Did you try? How is this helping the OP?

Comment: if I do alert(myString) I see Citt&agrave;

Comment: Yes, I tried and it shows perfectly. But I realized the problem he's having is that he gets the string with the HTML code for "à".

Comment: @Victor : yes, that's the problem!

Comment: Ok, so if you get this string from C#, I think you can use `HttpUtility.HtmlDecode` to get the original text, and then show the alert.

Comment: Yeah, that's will work ;) That's a bit dangerous if a user Insert some other javascript code, isn't it? :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the Unicode character. This example uses the escaped form.

```
alert("Citt\u00e0");
```

This worked fine for me.

EDIT: see [this page](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/e0/index.htm) for reference (scroll down to "Encodings")

EDIT THE SECOND:

You might need to do a string replace on your returned value from the database.

```
var myString = "Citt&agrave;";
alert(myString.replace("&agrave;","\u00e0"));
```

Comment: I take the string from DB. I can't insert that string :)

Comment: This won't resolve the problem is my string will be é :) There isn't a sort of HTML decode on jquery? :)

Comment: @markzzz - Javascript does not have an HTML decode. Some libraries (jQuery for example) do have such functionality.

Comment: Regarding *"You need to use the Unicode character."* **a)** What you have is not a Unicode character, but the *escaped form* of it. **b)** JavaScript can perfectly cope with the literal Unicode character as long as the correct encoding and Content-Type header is used to transfer it.

Comment: You're absolutely right about point a, and I've edited my answer to reflect that.