# How to clean up an exception string so it can be displayed via Javascript Alert?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I'm attempting to display an exception string in the time-honoured way:-

```
Page page = HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler as Page;

if (page != null && !page.ClientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered("alert"))
{
    page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(
                  typeof(Alert),
                  "alert",
                  "<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert(\"Fred\");</script>");
}
```

This works perfectly fine and displays the message as expected. If, however, I use a string supplied by some other part of the program:-

```
    page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(
       typeof(Alert),
       "alert",
       "<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert(\"" + error_message + "\");</script>");
```

no popup is displayed and an error occurs,

```
Unterminated String Constant
```

The string contains a deplorable number of control characters but not, as far as I can see, any `"` or `'` characters. Is there a function that can be invoked to clean up a string so that it can be displayed by a Javascript Alert? This fellow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6408954/how-to-display-correctly-this-string-on-an-alert-javascript) had a similar problem but no general solution was forthcoming.

Comment: Did you view the source and see what is actually outputted? I am guessing you got line breaks.

Comment: Try using [`Server.HtmlEncode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525347(v=vs.90).aspx) to escape the strings.

Comment: please visit this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/806944/escape-quote-in-c-sharp-for-javascript-consumption

Answer (score 3):

You need to serialize the message before displaying it as it will likely contain characters that are breaking your JS. You can use the [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) class

For example:

```
var errorMsg = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(error_message);
page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(
   typeof(Alert),
   "alert",
   "<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert(\"" + errorMsg + "\");</script>");
```

Comment: Supported in .NET 3.5+ only

Comment: @banging I can't see anything in the OP requiring a solution for a specific framework version. If this becomes an issue then I would recommend another option such as HTML encoding the string before it's rendered.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but the string produced with this produced an error complaining about a missing `)`, the position given being at the `y` in `type`. I've since tried the solution given in the question referred to in the comment by Sain Pradeep, which produces the expected output.